# How to you negate a Q object within a query?

Tags: django

I want to negate a Q object if a specific condition is met without having to duplicate multiple queries in a view.

I have tried breaking the query into multiple functions but I cannot help but think I still have a large amount of duplicated code.

```
query = User.objects.all()
if active:
  query.filter(Q(active=active))
elif active == False:
  query.filter(Q(active=active) | Q(active__isnull=True))
else:
  query.filter(Q(active__isnull=True) | Q(setup=False))
```

Comment: What is `setup=...` doing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about making complex querysets in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) but to **negate** a Q object queryset you can do:

```py
queryset = Model.objects.filter(~Q(active=active))
```